# PostgreSQL Select from 5 million rows table

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have table with about 5 million rows

```
CREATE TABLE audit_log
(
  event_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  action smallint, -- 1:modify, 2:create, 3:delete, 4:security, 9:other
  level smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 20, -- 10:minor, 20:info, 30:warning, 40:error
  component_id character varying(150),
  CONSTRAINT audit_log_pk PRIMARY KEY (audit_log_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I need to get all component ids with something like `SELECT component_id from audit_log GROUP BY component_id` and it takes about **20 seconds** to complete query. How can i optimise that?

**UPD**:

I have index on component_id

```
CREATE INDEX audit_log_component_id_idx
  ON audit_log
  USING btree
  (component_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

**UPD 2**: Well, i knew that one solution is to move component names to separate table, but hoped there was an easier solution. Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you mean, "select distinct component_id from audit_log"?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Well, distinct is faster for 2 seconds

Comment: It's the semantically correct way of writing the query. Using group by is just a longer and non-standard way of writing it.

Comment: Do you have a list of valid component_id's elsewhere, and if so how many of them are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an index on column component_id

As it is the only column used in your query you can then access the information directly from the index.

You might also want to consider moving the component (currently a string) into a separate table, referencing it by an ID of type integer or similar.

Comment: I have btree index. It does not help

Comment: what is the cardinality of the column? how many different values do you have? have you tried splitting the componnent info into the string value in a second table, and only the indexed integral ID in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Create a non-clustered index (component_id) for your table. Or define non-clustered for all field which you are using as part of your where class. Try to see the execution time difference or the execution plan. The bet would be to convert all scan to seek operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a list of valid component id's in another table and just wanted to check for their presence in the audit table, optionally with some conditions, then you might:

```
select
  component_id
from
  components
where
  exists (
    select null
    from   audit_log
    where  audit_log.component_id = components.component_id)
```

This would perform much better if the number of distinct component_id's was significantly smaller than the number of rows in the audit_log and the audit_log.component_id is indexed.